# Home Wifi Network with multiple PC's running different Windows versions

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, windows-xp, sharing

I have a home WiFi network set up with 4 PC's. Two of the PC's are running Windows 10, one is running Windows 7 and one is running Windows XP. Each of the PC's can "see" the others shared resources on the network. The Windows XP machine can access all of the shared files on the other 3 and the Windows 7 machine has no problem accessing shared files on either of the Windows 10 machines. Likewise, the Windows 10 machines can share files with each other and with the Windows 7 machine.

The issue that I am having is that when I try to access the Windows XP machine from any one of the other 3, I get a Windows Security Log On dialog that will not accept the Logon Credentials for the XP machine making it impossible to access the shared folders and the one printer that is attached to the XP machine.

I'll admit it, I really like the printer and want to continue to use it until it gives up the ghost. Thing is it's an older HP that is not supported beyond the Windows XP operating system.

My question is: How do I get the 3 newer OS's to Logon to the older XP machine, or is there a way to get around the Windows Security Credentials thing?

Comment: What model of HP printer? They are usually pretty good about keeping them working with later versions of windows, although you may have to install a generic HP PCL driver.

Comment: The printer is an HP Photosmart 7150 but it isn't the problem. I could print to it if I could get to it. I can't get past the login credentials to any of the shared resources including drives & files on the XP machine from any of the others. I was able to print to that same printer when it was connected to one of the other PC's but there is no room for the printer where those PC's are located.

Comment: You seemed to indicate that the printer wouldn't work on anything newer than XP in your question. Past that, I seem to recall that I could access my XP machine from a Windows 7 laptop, that was on the same home network or workgroup. I assume you have checked all the firewall and file sharing options on the XP machine?

Comment: Yes, I have even disabled the firewall and tried with the same results. I had the same logon credential dialog pop up for all of the other machines on the network and am able to log on to those PC's using the username and passwords that are set up for me (as a user of each) on those machines. The XP is the only one that I am unable to log on to. The only thing I haven't tried is to eliminate all users (myself and guest) on all PC's (no logon at startup). Currently they are all associated to the same WiFi network and work group.